# Will programs compiled with Delphi 2010 run on Windows 10 without problems?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, windows-10

Are there any problems with programs that are compiled with Delphi 2010, using Rave reports (no database connection) running on Windows 10?

Comment: Depends - are you using any Windows API calls which may have been deprecated since the version of Windows you designed it for?

Comment: Hell yes, I even have D5 apps smoothly running on W10...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle, there's no reason why a program compiled with Delphi 2010 will not work perfectly well on Windows 10. Indeed, a program compiled with any 32 bit version of Delphi (Delphi 2 or later) can, in principle, be executed on Windows 10.

The usual caveats apply though. You have to make sure that your code respects features like UAC. So don't attempt to write to HKLM, system directories, etc. as standard user.

As a broad guideline, if your program executes on Windows 8.1, you can expect it to execute on Windows 10 also.

So, in summary, you should be perfectly capable of producing a program that runs on Windows 10 using Delphi 2010. However, it's impossible for anyone to tell you definitively that your program will run because only you know the full details of how your program is implemented. You should test your program on each new operating system as it is released, if not before it is released.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, but the internal Kernel ID from Windows is set from 6.x (Windows Vista - Windows 8.1) to 10.0 (Windows 10) so this can be a problem.

Comment: Because a lot of programs check the kernel version before they start. So the most programs that run on Windows Vista also run on Windows 8.1 but it can be possible that this program not run on Windows 10 because the kernel version isn't 6.x but 10.0. Do you know what i want to say?

Comment: Do they? I've never encountered that. Do you have an example? A typical Delphi program won't do that. What's more, the changes to `GetVersionEx` will mean that the system will lie about the version anyway.

Comment: Delphi does not put that check in applications that you build with it. This would only be a problem if you have implemented this yourself, and in that case you would know about this so that also is not a problem